# flatMap GET and PUT request not returning results

Tags: angular, http, flatmap

I have a getUserInfo function that can successfully return the user's id, email, etc..
I also have a updateUserEmail function that uses a flatMap in order to consolidate the GET request( getUserInfo() ) to do server validation and then a PUT request. I've never used a flatMap before so I'm also trying to figure out where to do the validation. I'm not sure if I do the validation on the get UserInfo function, but it seems like the most logical place. I need to validate the GET request before the PUT request in case validation fails and I want PUT request not to happen.

Also I know I'm not using the userInfo value from flatMap. It's because I'm not really sure how to. It's not a server response where I can grab userInfo._id. I'm pretty new to all this so thanks for any help.

user service

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { UserEmailChange } from './emailChange.model';
import { flatMap } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { AuthService } from '../auth.service';
import { tap } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class ProfileService {
  userId = localStorage.getItem("userId: ");

  constructor(private http: HttpClient, private authService: AuthService) { }

  getUserInfo(id: string, oldEmail: string) {

    this.http.get(`http://localhost:3000/api/user/${id}`).pipe(tap(value => 'output: ' + "TEST" + value)).subscribe((res) => {


      if (this.userId === res["posts"]._id && oldEmail === res["posts"].email) {
        console.log("You passed the id and email test");
      }
      else {
        console.log("You failed the test!");
      }
    });

    }

    updateUserEmail(emailChange: UserEmailChange) {
      return this.getUserInfo(this.userId, emailChange.oldEmail)
      .pipe(flatMap(userInfo => this.http.put(`http://localhost:3000/api/user/${this.userId}`, emailChange )));
    }

}
```

user component

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ProfileService } from './profile.service';
import { AuthService } from '../auth.service';
import { UserEmailChange } from './emailChange.model';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-profile',
  templateUrl: './profile.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./profile.component.css']
})
export class ProfileComponent implements OnInit {
  userId: string;
  authenticated = false;
  emailResponse: string;
  idResponse: string;
  oldEmail: string;
  constructor(private profileService: ProfileService, private authService: AuthService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.userId = localStorage.getItem("userId: ");
  }

  onUpdateUserEmail(oldEmail: string, newEmail: string) {
    const userEmailChange = new UserEmailChange();
    userEmailChange.oldEmail = oldEmail;
    userEmailChange.newEmail = newEmail;


    this.profileService.updateUserEmail(userEmailChange).subscribe(emailUpdated => {



    });

  }


}
```

Currently in updateUserEmail() in the service, the .pipe is returning the error
`Property 'pipe' does not exist on type 'void'.ts`

Comment: The class methods you are trying to add pipeable operators to don’t return anything because you are using subscribe() in them. Don’t subscribe in these methods and instead return Observable<T> to be able to consume them with additional pipe() in other methods. If you need to perform side effects in methods like get user info, use a pipe there and an operator like tap/do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Alexander mentions, you aren't returning a value correctly from `getUserInfo`. You need to return the observable, then do what you need to do with it in the function you are returning it to

```js
getUserInfo(id: string, oldEmail: string) {
  return this.http.get(`http://localhost:3000/api/user/${id}`)
                  .pipe(
                    tap(value => 'output: ' + "TEST" + value),
                    tap(res => {
                      if (this.userId === res["posts"]._id && oldEmail === res["posts"].email)
                        console.log("You passed the id and email test");
                      else console.log("You failed the test!");
                    })
                  );
}

updateUserEmail(emailChange: UserEmailChange) {
  return this.getUserInfo(this.userId, emailChange.oldEmail)
             .pipe(
                flatMap(userInfo => this.http.put(`http://localhost:3000/api/user/${this.userId}`, emailChange))
             );
}
```